# jasmine: using function with a dot in the name

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, jasmine

I'm testing a js function that uses functions from other js files.

One of my external js files has a function defined as such:

functionname.functionextension = function () {.....}

when testing using jasmine, and calling functionname.functionextension, it complains that functionname is not defined. I think it believes that functionname is an object..

I know that one way to get around this is to modify the function name but I can't do that. Is there any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, all functions are objects. In the external js file, the function is probably defined like this:

```
var functionname = functionname || {};

functionname.functionextension = function () {
    ...
};
```

If you're getting a script error that `functionname` is not defined, there is either an error in the external javascript or you are not calling some initialization function that the external script requires to set up its objects.

Comment: hmm.. I see. It makes sense I can only see one place where it gets defined as var functionname= {}. I did that at the top of the jasmine test to reproduce but I get the error "Object #<Object> has no method functionextension"

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me...u need to call function by its full name like functionname.functionextension() while calling.